# Word meaning "compellingness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just came across a situation where a word meaning "having the quality of being compelling" would have been useful.  The sentence was along the lines of:

> He argued his case passionately.  I think this demonstrates the [compellingness] of Yale's philosophy degrees!

I could've paraphrased to something like:

> He argued his case passionately.  I think this demonstrates how compelling Yale's philosophy degrees are!

.. but in this case I think it would've made the whole sentence more clunky.  What I came up with in the end was 'vigor', but I don't like it; is there a word which more closely resembles 'compellingness' (which itself doesn't sound like a word to me, and the dictionary seems to back that up)?

Comment: Why would you call the degree compelling in the first place? Seems like an odd choice of words to me. More context might help.

Comment: I'll give it a while for OP to clarify. If not I'll vote to close because I have no idea what OP means by saying Harvard's computer science degrees are *vigorous and compelling*, apart from the implication that he thinks well of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The fact that the two words are nowhere close to synonyms doesn't help matters, either.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers here. The only way I can see for a degree to be compelling is if it "evokes attention" when spotted on a resume, or if it forces you to make a decision for a candidate with a Harvard degree over one from another school. Which do you mean, Jez?

Comment: @Jeff: Plausible for *compelling*, but how can you square that with *vigour*?

Comment: I cannot; like @onomatomaniak, I don't see how "vigor" could be a replacement for "compellingness".

Comment: @JeffSahol I'm using the following definition of "compelling": having a powerful and irresistible effect; requiring acute admiration, attention, or respect.

Comment: @Jez: I think it would help if you'd provided the missing context. Exactly what is "this", that demonstrates some quality of Harvard's degrees? All I can guess so far is that the quality itself might be something like [admirability](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Admirability), but this is a pretty vague concept if we don't know why we're supposed to admire these degrees so much. I've voted to close as *not a real question*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It refers to the passion of the person's arguments, which had presumably been caused by their degree's being... compelling.

Comment: @Jez That explanation doesn't enlighten me any further. How can the admirability of a degree make a person's arguments passionate? What does that even mean?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't talking about its admirability, was I?  I said about its being compelling.  Here's one definition of *compelling*: "having a powerful and irresistible effect; requiring acute admiration, attention, or respect".

Comment: The comment was from me, not @FumbleFingers. Are you reading the definition you're giving? If something "requires acute admiration", it is *admirable* and thus may be described as having *admirability*. But substitute "irresistible effect" or whatever you like into the question in my comment. The answer is still far from evident. I think you've simply chosen the wrong word.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I get people mixed up in these comments.  :-)  I guess the question comes down to the assertion on my part that the adjective "compelling" has its own unique meaning and so should have its own unique noun.  Why do we have the adjective "compelling" instead of just saying "admirable"?

Comment: Compelling does have a different meaning from admirable. And it's still the wrong word.

Comment: To me, there's nothing wrong with describing a degree as "compelling"; a degree which is so good/enjoyable/well-taught, etc. that it "compels" you to continue studying it?  What's 'wrong' with that?

Comment: @Jez: What's wrong with a *compelling degree course* is obviously that most people don't grasp what you mean by it, so it's a bad choice of adjective there. It's used for [compelling book/film](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compelling+book%2Ccompelling+film&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which I think is the sense you intend, but most of us simply wouldn't use the word *compelling* for an experience lasting perhaps several years.

Comment: +1, basically because of 'colorfulness' perhaps being recognized in computer science as similar but distinct to chroma and saturation. "x in nature" is such a barren and confusing expression, when we could have unified rules for any "word for property x" -> "word for amount of property x".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this demonstrates the compelling nature of Harvard's computer science degrees!

Answer (score 4):

*Irresistibility*? Or perhaps *allure*?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *cogency* fits the bill?

<s>EDIT: *compelling nature* would work well too.</s> Must not have looked again before editing.

Answer (score -1):

The word you're looking for **is** compelling, as it best suits the context. Here's another word that may suit.

*captivating*

> Attract and hold the interest and attention of; charm.

Comment: The word he's looking for, whatever it may be, is a noun.